# Calculate pseudo-median for many columns

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the pseudo-median (Hodges-Lehmann estimator) calculated from the wilcox.test function in R between several different columns in my dataset (8 separate fields/columns).

```
> head(fantasyproj2)
       V1        V2          V3  V4       V5       V6      V7          V8
1     25       25.87      20.35 26.65   27.20    27.0    17.970      27.70
2     24       27.48      19.81 19.57   22.20    27.5    16.350      20.04
3     22       19.89      17.62 21.99   19.12    26.0    22.484      23.70
4     21       17.72      16.09 15.55   18.60    18.5    17.450      14.59
5     21       21.56      17.90 18.46   20.80    23.0    16.540      19.76
6     20          NA      17.73 15.84   19.00    20.5    19.080      15.05
```

They are all numeric, and do include some missing values (the missing value have no data within them and have been changed to NA in R).  when I run the code:

```
fantasyproj$hodges.lehmann <- apply(fantasyproj2[,c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)],1, function(x) wilcox.test(x, conf.int=TRUE, na.action=na.exclude)$estimate)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in uniroot(wdiff, c(mumin, mumax), tol = 1e-04, zq = qnorm(alpha/2,  : f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

There is not much literature on this error out there [except](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-from-wilcox-test-td918306.html) where it says to add the argument `exact = TRUE`to the statement, but that does nto help.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't get that error when I run your code.

Comment: yep just saw that, and corrected.  still get the same result

Comment: Is the error being caused by some other row in your real data set? Try to narrow it down to the offending row and post that row of data.

Comment: FYI, instead of `c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` you can just do `1:8`.

Comment: I think that was it.  It seems some data was causing the issues where I only had one projection from the 8.  Thanks!!!